# Nginx retry same end point on http_502 in Docker service Discovery

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-swarm, high-availability

We use **docker swarm** with **service discovery** for Backend **REST** application. The services in swarm are configured with `endpoint_mode: vip` and are running in `global` mode. Nginx is proxy passed with service discovery aliases. When we update Backend services sometimes nginx throws 502 as service discovery may point to the updating service.

In such case, We wanted to retry the same endpoint again. How can we achieve this?

[According to this](https://hashnode.com/post/how-to-configure-nginx-to-hold-the-connections-and-retry-if-the-proxied-server-returns-502-cilngkof700iteq53ratetsry) we added upstream with the host's private IP and used `proxy_next_upstream error timeout http_502;` but still the problem persists.

#### **nginx.conf**

```
upstream servers {
    server 192.168.1.2:443; #private ip of host machine
    server 192.168.1.2:443 backup;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
    proxy_next_upstream http_502;
    location /endpoint1 {
        proxy_pass http://docker.service1:8080/endpoint1;
    }
    location /endpoint2 {
        proxy_pass http://docker.service2:8080/endpoint2;
    }
    location /endpoint3 {
        proxy_pass http://docker.service3:8080/endpoint3;
    }
}
```

Here if http://docker.service1:8080/endpoint1 throws ***502*** we want to hit http://docker.service1:8080/endpoint1 again.

**Additional queries:**

1. Is there any way in docker swarm to make it stop pointing to updating service in service discovery till that service is fully up?
2. Is upstream necessary here since we directly use docker service discovery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you add a health check directly at container level ([here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#healthcheck))

By doing so, docker pings periodically an endpoint you specified, if it's found unhealthy it will 1) stop routing traffic to it 2) kill the container and restart a new one. Therefore you upstream will be resolved to one of the healthy containers. No need to retry.

As for your additional questions, the first one, docker won't start routing til it's healthy. The second, nginx is still useful to distribute traffic according to endpoint url. But personally nginx + swarm vip mode is not a great choice because swarm load balancer is poorly documented, it doesn't support sticky session and you can't have proxy level health check, I would use `traefik` instead, it has its own load balancer.

Comment: Can you help me understand how health check is useful here? May be an explanation would help me and others to plot what is happening. I'm trying to eliminate upstream and do something in proxy pass to retry the same url, By doing this I'm trying to minimize another entire flow.

Comment: @Mani sorry I forgot you were using vip mode, see updated answer.

Comment: So I need to use traefik as load balancer and redirect proxy pass to it right?

Comment: Well I'd suggest replacing nginx with traefik.

Comment: Will suggest it to frontend. Anyways thanks I hope health check should do the job as of now.

Comment: If suppose we continue with nginx is the config given proper or does anything needs change?

Comment: I'm thinking of implementing Haproxy. May I know how traefik is better than nginx and haproxy? I'm researching the same but can't get clear idea.

Comment: Nginx config is still not working perfectly when I bring the service completly down and bring it up. In such case it throws 502. Is there something like auto discovery or resolving cached endpoints by clearing it?

Comment: @Mani could this be a problem on the container? Like it takes a while to start

Comment: I figured out added docker DNS 127.0.0.1 as resolver with 5s as validity and removed upstream. So each time when we are trying to proxy pass Nginx resolves it using Docker DNS. It's working fine. Thanks for all the help. Will add it as an answer as it might help someone else later.