# How to Make Docker use a Different Port, and maintain Apache2 Service in Plesk Obsidian

Tags: docker, port, plesk, obsidian

I have a docker application running on a server, which is also running Plesk Obsidian, running with Ubuntu. I have had to disable Apache2 so that the container can run, as the container automatically takes port 443. It would be preferable not to mash up the entire Apache2 service but changing those default ports.

If I were to change the port values in the domain's docker-compose.yml, and then restart the docker service and container, would this mean that I could run Apache2 elsewhere normally without having to alter the entire server?

For example changing the ports, in the domain's docker-compose.yml thusly:

```
services:
    nginx:
        image: nginx:${NGINX_VERSION:-1}
        container_name: nginx
        restart: always
        stop_signal: SIGTERM
        ports:
            - "443:444"
            - "80:88"
            - "8080:8888"
            - "2095:2096"
            - "2096:2098"
        volumes:
            - 'nginx-conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d'
            - './network_internal.conf:/etc/nginx/network_internal.conf'
            - './proxy.conf:/etc/nginx/proxy.conf'
            - 'letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt'
        networks:
            - nginx-proxy
```

and then open those ports (444, 88, 8888, 2096, 2098) in the Plesk Obsidian Firewall? Would that work?

Comment: Would it be possible to use proxy_pass as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53882200/how-to-shareexpose-port-80-for-multiple-projects-while-using-docker?rq=2